# How do I make the parameters in the user auth be dynamic?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, nuxt.js

My auth in nuxt.config.js like this :

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      home: '/home',
      logout: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'response.token'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/references?number=1122334433221&name=chelsea&birthDate=1995-03-18',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'data'
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/logout',
            method: 'post'
          }
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer '
      }
    },
    token: {
      name: 'token'
    },
    cookie: {
      name: 'token'
    }
}
```

In endpoint user, I put number, name and birthDate statically. How do I make it dynamic? So the parameter is taken from the data

```
data () {
    return {
      auth: {
        name: '',
        number: '',
        birthday: null
      }
    }
}
```

When submit login, it will call this :

```
methods: {
    submit () {
        this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
          data: {
            username: 'mycompany',
            password: '123123123'
          }
        }).then((resp) => {
          this.SET_IS_AUTH(true)
          this.$router.push('/home')
        }).catch(() => {
          console.log('error')
        })
    }
}
```

**Update** (Using try catch)

```
methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['SET_IS_AUTH']),
    async fetchUserInfo () {
      const user = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/references?number=${this.auth.number}&name=${this.auth.name}&birthDate=${this.auth.birthday}`)
      this.$auth.setUser(user)
    },
    submit () {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        try {
          this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
            data: {
              username: process.env.USERNAME,
              password: process.env.PASSWORD
            }
          }).then((resp) => {
            this.fetchUserInfo()
            this.SET_IS_AUTH(true)
            this.$router.push('/home')
          })
        } catch(err) {
          commit('SET_ERROR', err)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are setting the user endpoint in `nuxt.config.js` you won't be able to dynamically pass in the endpoint URL. However, you can achieve the outcome by passing false to the user endpoint like so:

```js
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      home: '/home',
      logout: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'response.token'
          },
          user: false,
          logout: {
            url: '/api/logout',
            method: 'post'
          }
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer '
      }
    },
    token: {
      name: 'token'
    },
    cookie: {
      name: 'token'
    }
}
```

Then you can use `axios` to make the request to get the user details manually passing in your dynamic values and then setting the user values for the `auth` module. For example perhaps when the user logs in, you can then have a method called `fetchUserInfo` and it would look like so:

```js
export default {
data () {
    return {
      auth: {
        name: '',
        number: '',
        birthday: null
      }
    }
},
methods: {
 async fetchUserInfo() {
    const user = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/references?number=${this.auth.number}&name=${this.auth.name}&birthDate=${this.auth.birthDate}`)
    // Sets the user info using the setUser method on the auth module
    this.$auth.setUser(user)
  }
}

}
```

Here is a link to the `setUser` method usage. Perhaps this would help you: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth.html#setuser-user

Comment: I update my question. When did I call `fetchUserInfo `? When the response is successful?

Comment: Yeah when the user successfully logs into your application.

Comment: There exist parameter number, name and birthday. what if the input parameters are incorrect?

Comment: It would fail that’s what you have to account for also. Perhaps wrapping the network call in a try catch block

Comment: I have not tried it. I just make sure whether the flow is correct. Maybe I will move it to store (vuex store)

Comment: Okay that would be nice

Comment: where should we call this fetchUserInfo on refresh of page?

Comment: You can do so in mounted lifecycle hook.